# "libsass bindings not found. Try reinstalling node-sass"

Tags: node.js, centos, node-sass

So today I was trying to install MeepBot for StreamMe, and I ran into the error that says: "'libsass' bindings not found. Try reinstalling 'node-sass'." I reinstalled it like a million times. I have tried: "npm un/install --save-dev node-sass," "npm rebuild node-sass," etc. Can someone please give me an answer to my problem?

Picture: http://prntscr.com/axbxu8

P.S. keep in mind, I am using CentOS 6.

Comment: @ Revin Bray Which version on node you are using?

Answer (score 1):

According to `node-sass` project's [**README.md**](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#rebuilding-binaries) only binaries for "popular platforms"(i.e. Windows/Mac) are included and you may need to build for other platforms like CentOS.

Here are roughly the steps (reading the [readme](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#rebuilding-binaries) would give you a better idea):

```
 - cd to the node-sass directory within your project source.
 - node scripts/install.js
 - node scripts/build.js
```

Should see a message like Binary is fine; exiting.
Try to run  `npm rebuild node-sass` again and it should work!

Comment: I should have added this to my previous answer's comment but it has too many characters to add as a comment. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried reinstalling everything? `rm -rf node_modules; npm i`. i've had to do that multiple times before.

otherwise, `npm rebuild node-sass` should work unless there are multiple versions of `node-sass` in your dependency tree - then maybe not. are you using npm v3+?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try upgrading your [gcc compiler](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos) as node-sass uses gcc to compile. And then try this -

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

If that doesn't work then try runing this code (you must be using node version 4 or above).

```
npm install -g n
rm -R node_modules/
npm uninstall --save-dev node-sass
npm install --save-dev node-sass@2
npm install
npm -g install node-gyp@3
npm rebuild node-sass
```

If you are using multiple version of node then you will have to run `npm rebuild node-sass` every time you change node version.

You can also use gulp-sass `npm install gulp-sass@2` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue. In my case the parent package.json was referring to new version of node-sass but the version of gulp-sass was referring to old node-sass. As soon as I updated gulp-sass to latest version, and ran 'npm rebuild node-sass', issue was gone.